# Heroku connecting to random postgresql server instead of MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, heroku, djongo

Currently i am working on a web app with Django and MongoDB (using Djongo).

I have connected the mongodb server succesfully on my pc and everything worked fine but when
i started deploying the project to heroku, it connected to a random postgresql server instead of my
mongoDB server. Heres my DATABASES settings in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'CLIENT': {
            'host': 'mongodb+srv://connectionstring',
            'username': 'name',
            'password': 'pass'
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: do u really want any one to help u

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figured it out (Heroku only allow a few types of databases and auto installs Heroku Postgres).